# Create HDF5 Group /Table if it does not exist

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I am building an HDF5 file using PyTables python package. The file would be updated everyday with latest tick data. I want to create two groups - `Quotes` and `Trades` and tables for different futures expiries.  I want to check if the group `Quotes` exists or not and if not then create it. What is the best way to do it in PyTables?

Here is a code snippet of where I am right now:

```
hdf_repos_filters = tables.Filters(complevel=1, complib='zlib')
for instrument in instruments:
    if options.verbose:
    hdf_file = os.path.join(dest_path, "{}.h5".format(instrument))
    store = tables.open_file(hdf_file, mode='a', filters=hdf_repos_filters)
    # This is where I want to check whether the group "Quotes" and "Trades" exist and if not create it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out.

I am using the `File.__contains__(path)` method in the `File` class in `PyTables`.

As per the documentation:

```
File.__contains__(path)
```

> Is there a node with that path?
>
> Returns True if the file has a node with the given path (a string), False otherwise.

[PyTables File class](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/file_class.html#the-file-class)

Answer (score 4):

Kapil is on the right track in that you want to use the `__contains__` method, although because it is a double underscore method it is not intended to be called directly rather through an alternate interface. In this case that interface is `in`. So to check a file `hdf_file` contains a group `"Quotes"` you can run:

```
with tables.open_file(hdf_file) as store:
    if "/Quotes" in store:
       print(f"Quotes already exists in the file {hdf_file}")
```